# how do you perform hadoop fs -getmerge on dataproc from google storage

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

How do you use getmerge on dataproc for part files which are dumped to the google storage bucket.
If I try this `hadoop fs -getmerge  gs://my-bucket/temp/part-* gs://my-bucket/temp_merged`
I get an error
`getmerge: /temp_merged (Permission denied)`

It works fine for `hadoop fs -getmerge  gs://my-bucket/temp/part-* temp_merged` but that of course writes the merged file on the cluster machine and not in GS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [fsshell documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge), the `getmerge` command fundamentally treats the destination path as a "local" path (so in `gs://my-bucket/temp_merged` it's ignoring the "scheme" and "authority" components, trying to write directly to your local filesystem path `/temp_meged`; this is not specific to the GCS connector; you'll see the same thing if you try `hadoop fs -getmerge gs://my-bucket/temp/part-* hdfs:///temp_merged`, and even worse, if you try something like `hadoop fs -getmerge gs://my-bucket/temp/part-* hdfs:///tmp/temp_merged`, you may think it succeeded when in fact the file did *not* appear inside `hdfs:///tmp/temp_merged`, but instead appeared under your local filesystem, `file:///tmp/temp_merged`.

You can instead make use of piping stdout/stdin to make it happen; unfortunately `-getmerge` doesn't play well with `/dev/stdout` due to permissions and usage of `.crc` files, but you can achieve the same effect using the feature in `hadoop fs -put` which supports reading from stdin:

```
hadoop fs -cat  gs://my-bucket/temp/part-* | \
    hadoop fs -put - gs://my-bucket/temp_merged
```